# orderby not found error in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a class library that I use to hold the Entity Framework Data Model for my database.  For testing purposes I created a class in the library named test.cs and added this code just to see if everything is working:

```
        var db = new EmailTestEntities();

        var x = from p in db.Emails
                orderby p.Created
                where p.EmailRouteID == 4
                select new {p.ID, p.MessageDate};

        foreach (var y in x)
        {
            var z = y.ID;
        }
```

Every thing works so I added the exact same code to my web application which has a reference to my library and a using statement for the reference.

However, I get the following error:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1<EmailTestLibrary.Email>'.  'OrderBy' not found.
```

Why does the code work in the library but not in my web code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you've referenced System.Data.Entity

HTH

Answer (score 6):

Did you add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var x = from p in db.Emails                
                where p.EmailRouteID == 4
                orderby p.Created
                select new {p.ID, p.MessageDate};
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.. using System.Linq fixed this for me

Comment: as I mentioned.. using the 'using System.Linq' directive