# LINQ in SQLite for Windows store app does not have 'ThenBy' to order by multiple columns

Tags: linq, sqlite, c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I have a Windows 8 store application and I'm using the latest version on SQLite for my database.

So I want to return some records from the database and I want to order them by more that one column. However SQLite doesn't seem to have the ThenBy statement? So my LINQ statement is below:

```
from i in connection.Table<MyTable>()
where i.Type == type 
orderby i.Usage_Counter
// ThenBy i.ID
select i);
```

So how do I sort by multiple columns in SQLite without doing another LINQ statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SQL-Net's LINQ implementation to sort by multiple columns, since it doesn't have `ThenBy` implemented.

You can work around this by using the `Query` method on the `connection`:

```
var sorted =
    connection.Query<MyTable>(
    "select * from MyTable where Type = ? order by Usage_Counter, ID",
    // you may have to cast to int here...
    type);
```

Another option is to use your result from above and call `ToList()` on it. You can then sort the results by multiple values:

```
var tables =
from i in connection.Table<MyTable>()
where i.Type == type 
select i;

var tmp = tables.ToList();

var sorted =
from i in tmp
orderby i.Usage_Counter, i.ID
select i;
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used your first example and it works fine. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

When using query syntax, you simply supply a comma-delimited list of fields to sort by:

```
from i in connection.Table<MyTable>()
where i.Type == type 
orderby i.Usage_Counter, i.ID
select i
```

With method syntax, you can use ThenBy:

```
connection.Table<MyTable>()
          .Where(i => i.Type == type)
          .OrderBy(i => i.Usage_Counter)
          .ThenBy(i => i.ID)
```

**Edit** - Sorry to be the downer here, but it appears you can't use Entity Framework with Windows 8 Store Apps: [Is EntityFramework available for Windows 8 Store Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335601/is-entityframework-available-for-windows-8-store-apps)

Comment: That doesn't work. As soon as I try to use the comma-delimited list I receive an error stating that ThenBy not found. Try it with SQLite.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? You may just be missing a necessary reference. See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940548/orderby-not-found-error-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: The full Error is: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'SQLite.TableQuery<MyTable>'. 'ThenBy' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'? It's very similar to question that you've posted but because it's a windows 8 store application I can't reference System.Data.Entity namespace and I already have System.Linq referenced.